# How can I create a readonly Observable that depends on an Angular @Input() value?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I often have the case where I need to define an Observable field that depends on the value from an Angular component @Input(), such as `@Input() id: string`.

I would like to write something like the following:

```
export class DataViewerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() id: string;

  readonly data$ = this.dataService.byId$(this.id))

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }
  ...
}
```

However, this does not work because the id field does not get populated until sometime after the constructor and before OnInit (https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

I often solve this problem by creating an extra private subject (e.g., `_id$`:

```
export class DataViewerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() id: string;

  private _id$ = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);

  readonly data$: Observable<Data> = this._id$.pipe(
    switchMap(id => this.dataService.byId$(id))
  );

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._id$.next(this.id);
  }
}
```

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxthoj?file=src/data-viewer/data-viewer.component.ts

Not awful, but is there a better way to do this? I thought one potential option would be to add a pipe that checks the Angular Lifestyle Hooks and doesn't continue until after initialization:

```
  readonly data$ = of(onNgInit).pipe(switchMap(() => this.dataservice.byId$(this.id)))
```

It seems that this sometimes works with:

```
  readonly data$ = of(null).pipe(switchMap(() => this.dataservice.byId$(this.id)))
```

<s>but that appears to be a race condition.</s>

EDIT: This is not a race condition. By piping from `of(null)`, the expression in the switchMap is not called until after the observables receives a subscription. As long as this happens in OnInit or in the HTML Template via an async pipe, the value of `id` will be present.

Comment: How would you decide if another implementation was better? Given that you depend on an input, which could change, passing the `next` value in `ngOnChanges` would make more sense than `ngOnInit` (when it's not guaranteed the value is available yet).

Comment: Re "better," I suppose I was looking for an option that didn't require I create another Subject/Observable. Yes, I will often change to `ngOnChanges()` if I need to be able to adjust for future changes to the `@Input` value. For this specific case, `ngOnInit()` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what others are suggesting with using a setter is a good idea.

Maybe one suggestion that hasn't been mentioned here is that if triggering the Observable in `ngOnInit` is enough for you it basically means that you want to initialise the Observable just once in components lifetime. Observables do nothing until you subscribe to them which in your case probably happens in your component's template.

So instead of using an intermediate `ReplaySubject` you can postpone accessing the `this.id` property until the Observable that needs it is created. You can do that by wrapping the Observable with [`defer()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/defer).

```
data$ = defer(() => this.dataService.byId$(this.id));
```

The `this.id` property will be read when `data$` is subscribed.

Your updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbadzg?file=src%2Fdata-viewer%2Fdata-viewer.component.ts

Comment: If the input property changes then you have an out of sync observable.

Comment: Yes, that's why its mentioned in my answer :).

Comment: This answer solves my use case, as the ID of the component is only set on creation. If the `Input() id: string` could change later, then I think we're destined to pipe from an intermediate Subject. Of note, I think the solution I mentioned in my question, `data$ = of(null).pipe(switchMap(() => this.dataService.byId$(this.id)))` is equivalent to this, although this is cleaner. In each case, the internal expression will not be evaluated until after something (e.g., `*ngIf="data$ | async as data"` in the HTML template) subscribes to it.

Answer (score 2):

### Input Setter

You can use a setter and push the value to a subject.

```js
idSubject = new BehaviorSubject('0')

@Input()
set id(id: string) {
  this.idSubject.next(id);
}
```

*If you want to hide the Observer part of the subject, you can use a getter with `asObservable()`. It's a good practice and looks like this:*

```
private _idSubject = new BehaviorSubject('0')

get id$() {
  return this.idSubject.asObservable()
}
```

*Note that every time you do this in a component, you create a local state. You are probably better of doing this in service for a shared state between components. Or better yet to implement some sort of state management.*

### State Management

Here's a brief summary of some options that I know of:

- NgRx
- NgRx-data (NgRx wrapper - less boilerplate)
- Observable Store
- Akita
- Ngxs
- MobX
- Some custom implementation

Answer (score 0):

Use a setter

```
export class DataViewerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() id: string;
  set id(id: string) {
    this.dataService.byId$(id);
  }

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the property approach is the cleanest way to handle this.  However, an alternative approach would be to use [ngOnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) hook.  This hook is called every time there are changes to a value decorated with *Input*.  You can check if a particular property changed, and then call *next()* on a subject that is subscribed to in an observable that calls the *dataService*.

```
export class DataViewerComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() id?: string;

  private idChange = new Subject<string>();

  data$: Observable<Data> = this.idChange.pipe(
    switchMap(id => this.dataService.byId$(id))
  );

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.id) {
      this.idChange.next(changes.id.currentValue);
    }
  }
}
```

While I have not tried it, I know of a library called [ngx-observable-lifecycle](https://github.com/pdtec/ngx-observable-lifecycle) that would potentially work like your desired approach.

```
export class DataViewerComponent implements OnChanges$ {
  @Input() id?: string;

  data$: Observable<Data> = this.ngOnChanges$.pipe(
    // make sure id property changed.
    filter((changes): changes is { id: SimpleChange } => !!changes.id), 
    switchMap(changes => this.dataService.byId$(changes.id.currentValue))
  );
}
```